# Android state of switch changes when scrolling in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter in a listview. Every rows have a switch. I change every switch's checked according to my arraylist in custom adapter. It works normally but if I set checked of a switch manually and I scroll listview, checked of the switch changes to it's first value. Have can i solve this issue?

Comment: You have to change the state of the switch toggle on both cases.  The list is recycling its views, so it will preserve the state of the row when it is recycled back onto the screen.  Makes sure you set the switch explicitly for _both_ states (ie: on / off)

Comment: when i click the switch, it's state changes, doesn't it? I can even handle checked of the switch with setOnCheckedChangeListener. But how can i protect this value on listview when scroll?

Comment: You will have to update your data model.  The item that you are switching (checking) needs to correspond to an item in your data.  For example: something in your data needs to have a boolean value to determine if the switch is OFF or ON next time your view comes around.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are recycled when the list is scrolled. 
Make sure to set the switch to the right state  in the getView of your adapter.
If you manually change the state of the switch, you should save its state so that you can set it to the right value when the list is scrolled.

Comment: how can i save it's right value? Should i write in setOnCheckedChangeListener? I don't understand because, if it call setOnCheckedChangeListener , this means it's checked changed. Am i wrong? Why should i save it again?

Comment: As others have already said, you have to update your data model. I believe you have a list of objects representing the items in the listview. You should keep there the state of the switch (ON or OFF). When the list is scrolled, and the getView is called, you should read the state and set it to the switch.

Comment: yes, i updated my arraylist data only that position for switch value when switch state changed. It works. Thanks.

Comment: @crowde That worked for me!! Tank you!! It was so simple and logic. Thanks!